# TFS2015 Document library- open file instead of download

Tags: tfs-2015

when i am trying to view files from my TFS document library it's download the file instead of opening it automatic with excel OR word that are already installed on my pc, does someone know how to fix it?
i am using office365 and TFS2015 as you can see at the screenshot that attached this is how it's look like in PC that working fine.

[image]

Comment: Are you trying to open the document directly from the browser or Visual Studio Team explorer?

Comment: Any update on this issue?

Answer (score 0):

This kind of issue may related to your IE security setting, try to add the related sharepoint site in trust site and try again:

> 1. Close your browser (if you don't and you have your SharePoint site up you'll get a bunch of script errors because of the change to access
>      levels).
> 2. Go to your Control Panel
> 3. Open Internet Properties
> 4. Select the Security tab.
> 5. Select **Trusted Sites**
> 6. Click Sites, and add the URL for your SharePoint site.

More details please refer this similar issue: ["Some files can harm your computer" dialog when I open a file from the document library](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/f4a657e7-16d9-40f2-9d3a-69f97588b3de/some-files-can-harm-your-computer-dialog-when-i-open-a-file-from-the-document-library?forum=tfsgeneral)

If the warning dialog is disappear, but when you open file still download. Then that behavior maybe defined by your browser. Try some other browser such as IE/Chrome/FireFox. Double check the integration/link of your browser  and Word,Excel.